# Serialized attributes not evaluating properly with form helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, form-helpers

I'm rendering a form with serialized attributes.  The attribute serialization works fine under normal usage, but now i'm trying to serialize a hash.  The view code looks like the following

```
<%= @item.seasonality_of_sales_pct.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= eval("f.label      :'seasonality_of_sales_pct[:#{key}]'") %>
    <%= eval("f.text_field :'seasonality_of_sales_pct[:#{key}]'") %>
<% end %>
```

The error I'm getting is `undefined method 'seasonality_of_sales_pct[:January]' for #<Item:0x007f01083edd38>`.  However, the line that is throwing the error is the second `eval`.  The first `eval` evaluates just fine.  I'm baffled as to why this might be happening.

In the controller, I am setting up an attribute like the following

```
@item.seasonality_of_sales_pct = {January: nil, February: nil, March: nil, September: nil}
```

Another question that could maybe be answered in the comments is: How bad does this code smell?  I'm not sure how the rails community feels about metaprogramming like this.  It hurts me a bit to do it, but seems to work most of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to be a bit more thorough than Khaled's answer, which was sort of right.  The reason that the first eval statement didn't cause the error was because `f.label` doesn't care what you give it.  `<%= f.label :fake_stuff %>` will just create a label called `Fake Stuff`.  I'm still not quite sure why the attribute didn't work.  If I had `f.text_field :seasonality_of_sales_pct`, I got a text box full of my hash.  Also, I got the labels to display the correct values.

I absolutely did not need to use evals here (I can hope it was only a moment of weakness).  Just do

```
<%= f.text_field :'seasonality_of_sales_pct[:"#{key}"]' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `form_for` and then use `f.text_field :some_attribute_name` then the object you are building the form for (in your case `@item`) mush have an attribute named `some_attribute_name`.

You get this error because `@item` has no attribute or method named `seasonality_of_sales_pct[:January]`

I also would point out that there is no reason to use `eval` in your form, it is a serious security risk, as code can be injected.

Comment: Then how is the first line evaluating?  Also, if I move the logic into the controller and render the html to a variable (`html = [LOOP]`) that I put in the view (`<%= raw html %>`), will the security risk be mitigated?  Or can someone still inject code back to the controller?